# ObjectiveC using XIB cell using in tableview and shifting of views programmatically for arabic from left to right

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, constraints, xcode8

[small box is view1 and big Box is view2]
[these are the simple constraint with these views]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i86s5.png)ObjectiveC IDE :  I already make my all cell for english but for arabic instead of making new cell class i want to shift programmatically all views from left to right like it start from right all views same just position change from left to right:

this is code i am using for arabic:

```
[view1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

 [view2 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];


 [self.superView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-40-[view2]-20-[view1(==20)]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view2,view1)]];
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Anyone can tell me what should i do to resolve this ?

Comment: small box should come to right and big box should come to left?